# using same handle for multiple python modules

Tags: python

I have multiple python files(modules) with API's in it, like utils.py, monitor.py, etc.. In the main python script that calls these libraries, I use utils.api_name1, monitor.api_name2, etc.

Instead of doing that, I just want to use "self.api_name1", "self.api_name2", etc.

how do I get this done? I think I need to use classes, import one another, etc.

Appreciate if you can show a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

You can freely assign python modules into variables. Let's use `datetime.datetime` as an example:

```
> import datetime
> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 12, 12, 25, 11, 306000)
```

You can assign it to a variable:

```
> f = datetime.datetime
> f.now()
datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 12, 12, 25, 11, 331000)
```

Or, since you want to use `self`, to a class member:

```
> class Foo(): 
> ..   def __init__(self): 
> ..     self.f = datetime.datetime 
> ..     
> foo = Foo()
> foo.f.now()
=> datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 12, 12, 25, 11, 380000)
```

http://repl.it/6Qk/1